# Why do overflow:auto and overflow:scroll position the scrollbar differently?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Let's say I want to arrange a couple of boxes in a row but also want to add a vertical scrollbar if the content becomes too high. (Which, in this example, it always is.)

The code below does the job well enough:

```css
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ffb3ae;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #ffec90;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="cell">dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="cell">consetetur</div>
  <div class="cell">sadipscing</div>
  <div class="cell">elitr</div>
</div>
```

I'd prefer, though, to set `overflow-y` to `auto` instead. However, **doing so positions the scrollbar differently, apparently shrinking the div**. It also makes the last box not fit into the row anymore, causing the row to break into two, which is a bit of a problem for me. (See below.)

```css
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ffb3ae;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto; // this is all I changed
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #ffec90;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="cell">dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="cell">consetetur</div>
  <div class="cell">sadipscing</div>
  <div class="cell">elitr</div>
</div>
```

- What exactly is happening here, and *why*? Is this intended behavior that's documented somewhere, or am I just screwing up something?
- What's the easiest way to fix this (other than keeping `overflow` set to `scroll`, of course)?

Comment: The spec says that _"The behavior of the 'auto' value is user agent-dependent"_

Answer (score 0):

I think the `white-space:nowrap` is default in behavior of *inline-block* where `overflow:auto` breaks this rule. You may add `white-space:nowrap` again after overflow:auto

```css
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ffb3ae;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #ffec90;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="cell">dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="cell">consetetur</div>
  <div class="cell">sadipscing</div>
  <div class="cell">elitr</div>
</div>
```